# How to Search for a file in the drive with asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my  Asp.net and C# web application ,i want to search for a file with file name or a wildcard in the hard drive (say C:\ for example)  and display the results in a tree view.How can we achieve this ?

Comment: The file can be present in sub directories as well?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714101/quickest-way-in-c-to-find-a-file-in-a-directory-with-over-20-000-files

Comment: AFAIK (correct me if im wrong), ASP cant access all the filesystem in the client machine wright? unless you install ActiveX object or some thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Examples");
FileInfo[] files = folder.GetFiles("MyFile*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```