# Verify if an app is running and start it if not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process

I need to open an application if it is not already running.

Ex: I check if the application is running, if not I should run it for it to stay running.

I've tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("location of the executable");
```

and it will work, however, **do not have the specific path of the application to open**.

Comment: If you don't have the path, what _do_ you have?

Comment: What do  you mean by "do not have the specific path"? You don't know where the  app is?

Comment: Have you considered using a named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)?  Your application can attempt to acquire the mutex at startup and exit if it is already held by another process.  Other processes can open the mutex to determine if it exists.  Or should you really be considering a Windows Service?

Comment: Are you looking for an executable other than the one you are making the call from?  i.e. You want to enumerate all running processes, through something like Process.GetProcesses() and launch something if it is not already opened.  That is how I am reading into this, at least.

Comment: I have the program name only. The specific location where it is installed and I have not got the ability to use the site specific policies for the network.

Comment: Yes Joseph.ferris. That's right. The problem is that I do not have the installation location. Just know that it is installed on the machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on your comment, detecting it is pretty straightforward. Just enumerate Process.GetProcesses() or look for it explicitly by Process.GetProcessByName(). There are various examples on the MSDN [GetProcesses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) documentation page.

Launching an arbitrary application, though, is not as simple. If it is in the environmental PATH variable, you can launch it without knowing the install location - Internet Explorer, for example, which you can run by just typing IExplore.exe in your Start->Run dialog on your machine.

If you are sure that the executable is going to be in the PATH, and by you implying in your post that you can already launch it via Process.Start(), that may suffice. You can just simply then put a conditional gate in to see if it is present in the running processes before invoking Process.Start() via a call to GetProcessByName - so something like:

```
var runningProcessByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
if (runningProcessByName.Length == 0)
{
    Process.Start("iexplore.exe");
}
```

You obviously would use the name of the application you are looking to check for / execute in place of "iexplore". Note that you are looking for the executable name without extension when you search for processes, yet are including it when you attempt to launch it.

**Update**

Here is a good example that can be easily modified for finding an arbitrary file or list of files in C#. Please bear in mind, if you are able to target any part of the path (for example, searching inside of *Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)*, if you can be sure it is in a Program Files variant), the search will be considerably quicker. You may also want to consider storing the search result locally once the file is found, etc.:

[Quickest way in C# to find a file in a directory with over 20,000 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714101/quickest-way-in-c-sharp-to-find-a-file-in-a-directory-with-over-20-000-files)

Comment: joseph.ferris Thank you.
It's almost what I'm needing. But when I call the system by Process.Start ("my system"), I do not have the specific path and without passing the full path'm not getting.

I need a solution specific to the Process.Start (), passing only the system name.

I thought at first look something like the system, then find out where the system is installed, so I would have the exact path where it is installed. That would be possible?

Comment: That is where the "ifs" start to come in.  If it is in the environment path, you can launch the process without the path.  However, if it is not, you may be able to come up with something to search the program files folder for a specific filename to get the path, etc.  There is nothing "out of the box" that is going to get you a path for an arbitrary executable that is in an unknown location, though.

Comment: Ok. To search the system you suggest something?

Comment: Added an example that was found here on SO.  Obviously, searching the local file system is going to be an expensive operation.  If the machines are under your sphere of influence, I would strongly recommend adding the path via configuration or user-specified during installation, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try mutex:

```
bool Creatednew;
Mutex mut=new Mutex(true,"someuniqeid",out Creatednew);
if(Creatednew)//this app isn't already running
{
//run your app
}
else
Debug.WriteLine("new app was terminated");
```