# How to get full file path from file name?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I get the full path for a given file?

e.g. I provide:

```
string filename = @"test.txt";
```

Result should be:

```
Full File Path = C:\Windows\ABC\Test\test.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to search the `test.txt` file on your drive and return its path or you do you want to attach some default path to the file ?

Comment: Since between the flag time and the changes done, here is the update link with exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714101/quickest-way-in-c-sharp-to-find-a-file-in-a-directory-with-over-20-000-files

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
string fileName = "test.txt";
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
string fullname = f.FullName;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. 
It is returning current directory,
But i required from all directories.

Answer (score 12):

Use Path.GetFullPath():

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx

This should return the full path information.

Answer (score 8):

You Can use:

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(FileName);
```

it will return the Full path of that mentioned file.

Answer (score 7):

**[Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)**

```
string dirpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

**Prepend** this dirpath to the filename to get the complete path.

As @Dan Puzey indicated in the comments, it would be better to use **[Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)**

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), filename)
```

Comment: And don't prepend it.  Use `Path.Combine` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I know my answer it's too late, but it might helpful to other's
Try,

```
Void Main()
{
string filename = @"test.txt";
string filePath= AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filename ;
Console.WriteLine(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Per the Microsoft Docs, the BaseDirectory is used by "the assembly resolver to probe for assemblies." It resolves to the executable path (not the working directory) such as "bin/Debug/...". Therefore, it will only solve the OP's question in certain edge cases where the working directory and executable directory are the same. In most other cases, the executable directory will not be accessible by the current user.

Answer (score 3):

try..

```
Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: If I understand the question, `MapPath` is indeed the way to go http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Comment: `HttpContext` won't be available in WinForms

Comment: Server.MapPath is for IIS/web based applications. The tag on the question is windows

Comment: i required for windows forms.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
string fileName = @"test.txt";
    string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string[] fullFilePath = Directory.GetFiles(currentDirectory, filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

it will return full path of all such files in the current directory and its sub directories to string array fullFilePath. If only one file exist it will be in "fullFileName[0]".

Answer (score 1):

```
private const string BulkSetPriceFile = "test.txt";
...
var fullname = Path.GetFullPath(BulkSetPriceFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current path:

```
string AssemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ToString();
```

Good luck!