# Make user browse and select a txt file for processing in c#

Tags: c#

I want the user to locate a txt file on his computer which will later be used by my code for analysis. Is there a way to do that? One possible way is to make user enter the path of txt file. But that's not how I would prefer it
Thanks

Comment: Is that a WinForms application?

Comment: Throw him a open file dialog; get the file path, store it somewhere for future use.

Comment: [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) did you google this at all?

Comment: Upvote tooltip says "This question *shows research effort*; It is useful and clear". Upvoter please read it before upvoting :\

Comment: do some research on the "Directory" class, follow this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714101/quickest-way-in-c-sharp-to-find-a-file-in-a-directory-with-over-20-000-files

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I did try googling it and also searched it on SF. It is a Console Application. I will try to make a winforms app for this. 
thanks all again.

Answer (score 1):

```
string filename;
var loadDialog = new OpenFileDialog { Filter = "Text File|*.txt", InitialDirectory = @"C:\Your\Start\Directory\" };
if (loadDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    filename = loadDialog.FileName;
```

Comment: Make user browse and select sounds a lot like a winform with openfiledialog. He also added this information in a comment. :)